# Drop Shadows in Andengine

Tags: android, opengl-es, andengine

How can I make a drop shadow effect in a text with Andengine?

I don't find anything talking about drop shadows for Andengine.

I have tried to put two texts one white and other black with the shadow but doesn't sound good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my perspective, From your designer you have to create sprite sheet of letters that you can use in text.

Following link help you in using image font for your game.

[Image Font for GLES1](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/image-font-t10551.html)

For GLES2 you have to use Bitmap Font.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to support android 2.2 and above the best solution is yours. you can place two texts in a `Relative Layout` and move one of them a bit left or right and top or down by changing the `layout_margin` :)

Comment: another idea would be to find a font file that is shadowed